# Javascript effiency with APIs

Tags: javascript, api

I was wondering if the code I have written is efficient (I am getting what I want), but it doesn't look appealing. Is there a better way to write this?

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

function get_height() {

  const height_url = 'https://somewebsite.info/api/someth/tip/height';

  var data = fetch(height_url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log("The current height is " + data)
    })
}

get_height()
```

Comment: Better way: return the Promise (most functions that create Promises should return them), add a `catch` somewhere (probably on the outside consumer). Other than that, looks OK, efficiency isn't an issue here

Answer (score 0):

you can use async/await

```
async function get_height() {

    const height_url = 'https://somewebsite.info/api/someth/tip/height';

    var data = await (await fetch(height_url)).json();

    console.log("The current height is " + data)
}
```

Comment: Note that `async`/`await`, if transpiled, will be *significantly less efficient* than `.then`s

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't know it - do you have some link to test or it is from your experience?

Comment: Just plug it into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to see - not only that, it also requires RegeneratorRuntime, which is *huge*. If OP is looking for efficiency, and this is targeted at less modern browsers, probably best to keep using `.then`